# ffmpeg - can't concat because of corrupted video file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, corruption, dts

I'm trying to concat 5 video files taken by my gopro. The problem is that the 5th file is a little corrupted because the gopro ran out of battery and I guess some stuff didn't get saved correctly.

I can still play this 5th file in any player, upload it on YouTube, use it in Vegas pro, it just has some visual glitches every few and then.

When trying to concat the 5 files in ffmpeg, everything is fine for the 4 first files but when the 5th get processed I get a ton of ***"Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0 This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file."*** errors, and the output video just doesn't include the data from my 5th video.

I've tried everything to make this 5th video usable. Re-encode it to different formats, Re-render it using Vegas pro, uploaded it to different video streaming websites and downloading their proccessed version, I even got as far as to record it playing from vlc using obs, but EVERY time the video obtained couldn't be concated with the 4 first. I was still getting the DTS error and the output didn't include the footage.

**What can I do?** I don't even understand how footage recorded through obs could get the same corrupted data as the source file.